# DAX Total by category displayed for single category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want a total by category for single category. Just like the FruitOnly measure in a picture:

[image]

I have a measure:

```
Total by category = CALCULATE([Sales], ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Category]))
```

But I want the results only for Fruit, having blanks for all the other categories.

```
FruitOnly = IF(MAX('Table'[Category])="Fruit", [Total by category], BLANK())
```

Such a result is cripple because there is no total sum for that measure which should be 45.

Wouldn't there be any simpler way to get the FruitOnly results? Just like the measure:

```
Fruits raw sales = CALCULATE([Sales], 'Table'[Category]="Fruit")
```

returns the results only for fruits?

And now the bonus question lifting the challenge to Darth Vader level. Would a measure resulting in FruitOnly be possible if there was no Category displayed in table visual, just Product?

My desperate efforts are here in a file to download:

[TotalByCategoryForSingleCategory.pbix](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1sWVb3Qpg8uJk6sNImZPbJAwawIqXVCDj&export=download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
FruitOnly =
CALCULATE (
    [Total by category],
    FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Category] = "Fruit" )
)
```

I tried it out with your .pbix and I got the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! It had to be that simple. Thanks!

Comment: sure np can you accept my answer as the solution please?

Comment: If it was to be done in one measure then nested `CALCULATE` would be nesesery? I usually accept answers in 2 days leaving the question open to fresh ideas. I voted it up so far:-)

Comment: oh well that is just bad juju... to answer your question, yes you would need to nest the calculate statements.