# DAX measure to apply same value to each month

Tags: dax

I'm trying to consolidate a Year End projection that I got working using multiple measure. I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to get September's value to show in all months.

*Note* This is not the completed code.

This worked perfectly for my CompMoCI variable. I can't get it to work for my HisCompMoAvg variable.

```
SAIFI YEP = 
var CurYr = YEAR(TODAY())
var CurMo = MONTH(TODAY())
var Yr1Back = CurYr - 1
var Yr2Back = CurYr - 2
var Yr3Back = CurYr - 3
var Yr4Back = CurYr - 4
var Yr5Back = CurYr - 5
var CurYrCI = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([CI by Data Naming Convention], 'Date Table'[Date]), 'Year'[Year] = CurYr)
var CompMoCI = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([CI by Data Naming Convention], 'Date Table'[Date]), 'Year'[Year] = CurYr, 'Date Table'[Monthnumber] = (CurMo-1), ALLSELECTED(Outages), ALLSELECTED('Date Table'), ALLSELECTED(Customers))
var Yr1BackCI = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([CI by Data Naming Convention], 'Date Table'[Date]), 'Year'[Year] = Yr1Back)
var Yr2BackCI = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([CI by Data Naming Convention], 'Date Table'[Date]), 'Year'[Year] = Yr2Back)
var Yr3BackCI = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([CI by Data Naming Convention], 'Date Table'[Date]), 'Year'[Year] = Yr3Back)
var Yr4BackCI = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([CI by Data Naming Convention], 'Date Table'[Date]), 'Year'[Year] = Yr4Back)
var Yr5BackCI = CALCULATE(TOTALYTD([CI by Data Naming Convention], 'Date Table'[Date]), 'Year'[Year] = Yr5Back)
var HisTotal = CALCULATE(Yr1BackCI + Yr2BackCI + Yr3BackCI + Yr4BackCI + Yr5BackCI, ALLSELECTED(Outages), ALLSELECTED('Date Table'[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Customers))
var HisTotalAvg = CALCULATE(HisTotal, ALLSELECTED(Outages), ALLSELECTED('Date Table'), ALLSELECTED(Customers))/5
var AvgMoAhead = if(MAX('Date Table'[Monthnumber]) >= CurMo, HisTotalAvg, 0)
var HisCompMoAvg = CALCULATE(HisTotalAvg, 'Date Table'[Monthnumber] = 9, ALLSELECTED(Outages), ALLSELECTED('Date Table'), ALLSELECTED(Customers))
var test = HisCompMoAvg
return test
```

Comment: Please read that https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and leave only necessary code to reproduce your issue. Also think of desired results to show us direction.

Comment: So I'm getting something like this for HisCompMoAvg;
Jan = 13, Feb = 32, Mar = 45, Apr = 61, May = 77, June = 85, July = 98, Aug = 109, Sept = 130, Oct = 151, Nov = 178, & Dec = 196.


I would like to see;
Jan = 130, Feb = 130, Mar = 130, Apr = 130, May = 130, June = 130, July = 130, Aug = 130, Sept = 130, Oct = 130, Nov = 130, & Dec = 130.

Comment: Please reword your question. Start from initial data you have put in your comment. Then desired results. Explain how you get 130 from your initial data. I could not guess it. It is not an average.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be reworded. We can only guess what you want.

```
+-------+-------+-----------------+
| month | sales | expected result |
+-------+-------+-----------------+
| Jan   |    13 |             130 |
| Feb   |    32 |             130 |
| Mar   |    45 |             130 |
| Apr   |    61 |             130 |
| May   |    77 |             130 |
| Jun   |    85 |             130 |
| Jul   |    98 |             130 |
| Aug   |   109 |             130 |
| Sep*  |   130 |             130 |
| Oct   |   151 |             130 |
| Nov   |   178 |             130 |
| Dec   |   196 |             130 |
+-------+-------+-----------------+
```

Question. How to construct a DAX measure which shows September sales for all the months?

```
!Sales = SUM('Table'[sales])

YourMeasure = CALCULATE([!Sales], ALL('Table'[month]), 'Table'[month]="Sep")
```

Read about functions ALL, CALCULATE, and KEEPFILTERS.

[DAX Calculate function with and without FILTER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50506030/1903793)

[Difference between CALCULATE(m, x=red) vs CALCULATE(m, KEEPFILTERS(x=red))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57850298/1903793)

[DAX Total by category displayed for single category](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57596116/1903793)